# JavaScript UTC to LocalTime conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert UTC datetime to Local Timezone.

I am using function given below (i.e. I found from stackoverflow link) :

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {

    alert(date); // gives Wed Feb 05 2014 12:43:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) - This is UTC
    var newDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    alert (newDate); // gives Wed Feb 05 2014 12:43:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

    alert("getTimezoneOffset : " + date.getTimezoneOffset()); // gives getTimezoneOffset : -330 
    alert("getHours : " + newDate.getHours()); // gives getHours : 12
    alert("getMinutes : " + newDate.getMinutes()); // getMinutes : 43

    var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    var offset2 = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var mins = date.getMinutes();

    newDate.setHours(hours - offset);

    alert("getHours after : " + newDate.getHours()); // gives getHours after : 17
    alert("getMinutes after : " + newDate.getMinutes()); // gives getMinutes after : 43
    // See, the minutes are not updated
    return newDate;
}
```

Here, I am getting Hours are set but not the minutes. How to set Date and time (with hour,minutes and seconds) from UTC to local?

Comment: What do you mean the minutes are not set? Are they 0? What are the minutes in the original `date`?

Comment: before conversion, they were 43, after conversion they are still 43. It should be 13.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware some time zones were different by minutes, instead of just hours. In that case, this code just doesn't modify the minutes. It only ever sets the hours. Hence why the minutes don't change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example for the same,

```
var d=new Date("2014-02-06T13:14:15Z");
alert(d.toString());
```

Comment: Have you checked it? Can you give me the value are you passing in "date"?

Comment: Dude !! I am getting Invalid date. What do you think?

Comment: sorry, my mistake: Check my answer Update.
and can you give your `INPUT`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working using an user-defined function below :

```
function utcToLocal(utc) {
    // Create a local date from the UTC string
    var t = new Date(Number(utc));

    // Get the offset in ms
    var offset = t.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

    // Subtract from the UTC time to get local
    t.setTime(t.getTime() - offset);

    // do whatever
    var d = [t.getFullYear(), t.getMonth(), t.getDate()].join('/');
    d += ' ' + t.toLocaleTimeString();
    return d;
}
```

I found it from stack-overflow link, but unfortunately I closed it so I have placed the code of the function here.